# JAVA узнать расположение файла по его процессу

Tags: java

Собственно список процессов получаю примерно так. Можно ли как-то узнать расположение файла, исходя из его процесса? Интересует и для windows и для unix

```
public static class List {

    private static Set<String> exclude = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("SearchFilterHost.exe");

    public static StringBuilder list() {


        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\" + "tasklist.exe /FO CSV");
            try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(input).getRecords().stream()

                        .map(r -> r.get(0)).filter(item -> !exclude.contains(item))
                        .forEach(item -> b.append(item + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: Вы собираетесь tasklist.exe для никсов запускать?
Вообще, задача решается через WinAPI, но Java с ним смотрится несколько странно...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов конечно не собираюсь, это под винду просто код. Под unix только планирую ,а интересует для обеих систем. А без WinAPI не обойтись?

Comment: Без WinAPI не обойтись под виндой никак: все что вы будете делать рано или поздно будет дергать его. Либо прямо и понятно, либо через 33 прослойки...